# angularjs show last 5 items in ng-repeat list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list which logs previous names that I have chosen as shown below.  What I want is for the list to always only show the last 5 results, however what I have at the moment is showing the first 5 in order of time with latest first.  How can this be achieved?

http://jsfiddle.net/sfqo2fn3/1/

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="updatedname" />
        <input type="button" value="Change name" ng-click="changeName(updatedname)"/>
        <br/>
          Hello, {{name}}!
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="name in nameLog | limitTo:5 | orderBy:'time':true">{{name.value}} - {{name.time}}</li>
    </ul>    
    </div>

    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    myApp.factory('UserService', function() {
                var _nameLog = [];
                var userService = {};
                userService.name = "John";
                userService.ChangeName = function (value) {
                    userService.name = value;
                };
                userService.logName  = function (value) {
                    _nameLog.push ({
                        "value":value,
                        "time" :Date.now()
                    });
                };
                userService.getNameLog = function(){ return _nameLog; }
        return userService;
    });

    function MyCtrl($scope, UserService) {
        $scope.name = UserService.name;
        $scope.updatedname="";
        $scope.changeName=function(data){
            $scope.updateServiceName(data);
        }
        $scope.updateServiceName = function(name){
            UserService.ChangeName(name);
            UserService.logName(name);
            $scope.name = UserService.name;
            $scope.nameLog = UserService.getNameLog();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can do: `| limitTo: -5`

```
<li ng-repeat="name in nameLog | limitTo:-5 | orderBy:'time':true">...</li>
```

From [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo):

> **limit:** The length of the returned array or string. If the limit number is positive, limit number of items from the beginning of the source array/string are copied. If the number is negative, limit number of items from the end of the source array/string are copied. The limit will be trimmed if it exceeds array.length

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom filter for this. I have modified your fiddle a little bit:

http://jsfiddle.net/sfqo2fn3/2/

```
myApp.filter('slice', function() {
    return function(arr, start, end) {
      if(!end) {
          return (arr || []).slice(start);
      }
      return (arr || []).slice(start, end);
    };
});
```

You now have a "slice" filter that will filter to only show the last 5 items in the array.